# [PHP Warning: mail(): " sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing

Tags: php, email

I am trying to use PHP's mail() function to send a test mail.

```
$to = "****@gourab.me";
$sub = "Php Mail";
$msg = "Test Message From PHP";

mail($to, $sub, $msg, "From: **********@gmail.com");
```

When I try to debug it through `step` in `phpdbg`, it shows the message:

```
[PHP Warning: mail(): " sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header 
missing in C:/xampp/htdocs/tinyProj/mail.php on line 4]
```

I cannot understand why?

Comment: Bulk, the question reads quite clearly as, "I cannot understand why? Does anyone else?"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It seems your `From` header is not correctly formatted. Try this instead:

```
$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'From: Your name <info@address.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: I tried that but now phpdbg is showing `[PHP Warning: mail():  Failed to connect to mailserver at localhost port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()`

Comment: Are you on a live server or just your PC?

Comment: I'm on my PC with XAMPP

Comment: That's the problem, sendmail/postfix service is not running

Comment: It's off the main topic, you should open different question. Try the code on a shared/dedicated server or virtual machine or whatever and see it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69145/discussion-between-gourab-nag-and-fillobotto).

Answer (score 5):

Bro it seems that you're using you own PC/localhost/127.0.0.1 server that's why you can't connect to SMTP server. You can only send mail from live server using similar coding with some amendments :) i.e. add one parameter "Header/From".

```
mail("You@me.com","Answer","Hope You Vote My Answer Up","From: me@you.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
     $from =  $_POST['femail'];
     $phoneno = $_POST['phoneno'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];
     $carrier = $_POST['carrier'];
     if(empty($from)){
       echo("enter the email");
       exit();

     } 
else if(empty($phoneno)){
   echo("enter the phone no");
     exit();
   }
 elseif(empty($carrier)){
   echo("enter the specific carrier");
   exit();
    }
 else if(empty($message)){
  echo("enter the message");
  exit();
  }
  else{
     $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
     $header = $from;
     $subject = 'from submission';
     $to = $phoneno.'@'.$carrier;
     $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
     echo("message sent to".$to);

  }

  }
?>
```

Comment: Dear Yusuph, when answering this kind of question you should try to be more direct, the question says it is receiving an error message but it seems to be alright with code.