# Why is this e-mail form using validation resulting in an error?

Tags: php

error i'm getting is "Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing"

```
  else
  {
      $emailTo ="me@domain.com";
      $subject =$_POST['subject'];
      $content =$_POST['content'];
      $headers = "From : ".$_POST['email'];

      if (mail( $emailTo,  $subject , $content, $headers))
      {
          $successfulMessage ='<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your message is sent,We\'ll get back to you soon </div>' ;
      } 
      else
      {
          $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>Your message coudn\'t be sent</strong></p> </div>' ; 
      }

  }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *From* header is incorrectly formatted. Change

```
$headers = "From : " . $_POST['email'];
```

to

```
$headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'];
```

But I'd suggest something more extensive like in the answer found here:
[[PHP Warning: mail(): " sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026932/php-warning-mail-sendmail-from-not-set-in-php-ini-or-custom-from-head)

And just in case you're not running Unix and encounter the smtp error after this: [Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25)

Comment: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()    i'm getting this error now

Comment: That's why I provided the last link, it'll point you towards the solution of that error.